# How percentage works in css

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in HTML and CSS. Today I want to make a checkout form like that:[image]

I want height of checkout-option-header equal 50% checkout-option's, but It always bigger than I want. Like that:
[image]

As I understand the percentage will determine size of children by size of parents.

But why I can't use it right?

**CSS file:**

```css
.checkout-container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.checkout-container .checkout-option {
  margin: 5%;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.review-container {
  margin: 5%;
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.information-container {
  margin: 5%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.checkout-container .checkout-option .checkout-option-header {
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 50%;  
}

.checkout-option-container {
  background: green;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML file:**

```html
<div class="checkout-container">
  <div class="checkout-option">
    <div class="checkout-option-header"></div>
    <div class="checkout-option-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="review-container"></div>
  <div class="information-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have just use height property to determine size of children, It works, but can anybody tell me why min-height doesn't work? Thanks so much.

Comment: This works as it should. The `min-height` set on the `header` will grow beyond 50% if its content gets bigger, so if it always should be 50% of parent, you should use `height`

Comment: @help-info.de I don't know why but it works exactly what I want when I run in snippet, but when I copy to my project, It does not work right. :(

Comment: @LGSon Sorry but i don't understand exactly what you mean. :(

Comment: I mean if you want a height to be 50% of its parent, use `height`, if you want it to be minimum 50%, use `min-height` ... `min-height` mean it will grow larger than 50% if the content demands it, but never smaller

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I actually understand what you are asking but your code seems to be working.

http://codepen.io/TheStonedTurtle/pen/NbNNxw

I copied your code added the below CSS.

```
.checkout-option {
   border: 5px solid white;
}
```

If you're whole question is trying to understand how percentages work they are dependent on the parent element. I.E. if you have an element with 500px height and you give a child 50% height it will have 250px as that is 50% of 500. See these for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage

You could also use flexbox to accomplish this with less CSS but it is a relatively new feature so it is not fully supported in I.E. yet. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flexbox browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Technically no. If you have a parent element with 500px height, and an element with 50% height in it, then you get an element, whose height is (500 - parentPadding - parentBorder - childrenMargin)/2 px. (If you don't have boxSizing on, otherwise the parentBorder doesn't count

Comment: I don't know why but it works exactly what I want when I run in snippet, but when I copy to my project, It does not work right. :(  I run my project with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code but I didn't see such problem. The two boxes inside the `.checkout-option` are exactly 50% in height. Instead of `min-height`, use `height` because your `.checkout-option` is blocking the `checkout-option-header`.

Comment: I don't know why but it works exactly what I want when I run in snippet, but when I copy to my project, It does not work right. :(  I run my project with laravel, if It has any effectiveness. :(

Comment: Maybe the laravel??